# How to make a clean branch with a single commit

Tags: git

I have the following git structure :
[image]

The red branch is the main branch, then there is a multitude of smaller branch and commit.

I would like to do the following =>
[image]

Some of the commit on other branch ( not the red one) naming and stuff are not good.

I would like to merge a commit from the green branch, assign it a name like v0.1 and that this commit do not keep any track of previous commits.

It is like I am pushing all the stuff from scratch on the red branch without having edited it before.

I know it is possible but I do not remember how.

Thanks

Comment: Check out the state you want, copy the wiring tree elsewhere, and start a new repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you want to do, but as I read your question, it's one of these cases:

- Do you want to include *all* the changes from `blue` and `green` to `red` in a singe commit?

  - When on branch `red`, use `git merge --squash green`. This will merge all changes done in `blue` and `green` branch, but there will only be one commit, that you can name however you want (i.e. `v0.1`).
- Do you want to include the changes from a single commit *without* merging the other changes from `blue` and `green`?

  - Create a new branch from `red` (when `red`is checked out, use `git checkout -b newBranch`)
  - Cherry-pick the commit whose changes you want to include (`git cherry-pick <commit-id>`)
  - Merge the new branch to `red` (checkout `red`, then `git merge newBranch`). Voilà: only the changes from the cherry-picked commit will be merged to your `red` branch.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I've understand your question correctly:

> Some of the commit on other branch ( not the red one) naming and stuff are not good.

So I assume that the red branch is good, and some commits on green branch are good, some are bad. The same goes for other (non-red) branches. The branches are relatively short (have 1-2-3 commits, but not hundreds).

> I would like to merge a commit from the green branch, assign it a name like v0.1 and that this commit do not keep any track of previous commits.

Ok, so first of all create a branch out of the red branch which is good:

```
git checkout red-branch

git checkout -b my-clean-branch
```

Now if you merge into this branch (like `git merge green`) the `my-clean-branch` will be polluted with bad commits as well. So you can `cherry-pick` only good commits from the green branch:

```
git log green-branch 
// identify good commits, lets say, commits 123 and 456 are good, and commit 789 is not

// while being on my-clean-branch
git cherry-pick 123
git cherry-pick 456 // or in one command as you with
```

At this point make sure, the `my-clean-branch` is good to proceed with. You can tag it as v1.0 if you wish (check out the `git tag` command)

> It is like I am pushing all the stuff from scratch on the red branch without having edited it before.

Assuming that `my-clean-branch` is good, you can just get the changes into red-branch:

```
git checkout red-branch
git merge my-clean-branch // or rebase if you want
```